# How should I integrate React with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I know there is a lot of similar information out there, but I couldn't find anything specific to my use-case...

I'm on rails 5.2 using webpack and react is installed (and functioning). I'm trying to update a semi-complicated filter page I have, which functions as a very large multi-select checkbox filter (using form_for with remote=true). When the user checks a box, an AJAX call is made to rails and new data is displayed. The form is created dynamically based on data in my postgres db.

I have a basic react filter component already created using static data and it is updating my state fine (still working on creating the actual query). I just need some direction with the BEST (as in 'the most correct that you would do for the company you work for even if it is more complex and takes more time') way to pass in data to my react component and render it with the dynamic data.

I've seen main types of ways to do this. The first (which seems like a terrible idea) is to render a dummy div element with data attributes and then read that into the react component. The second is to 'do it in the controller' or 'use an api'. Does this mean setting up your rails project with an api endpoint and calling it via the react component? Does it mean using your existing controller routes and making the call that way?

edit: I've also seen several gems being used like webpacker-react, react_on_rails

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going the API route. However, with Rails server-side rendering, I was getting two get requests, once via HTML and when the component mounted and made the API call, once again. I ended up switching the entire front-end to React because of this...

There must be an easier way to work this...